# run php file in ec2 from lmabda with limited access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

i have a lambda function make POST request to AWS EC2 server by url (https://sub.domain.com).
right now the ec2 port 80 / 443 can access from anywhere and the lambda working fine and do the job.

for security reasons i need to block traffic in  AWS EC2 port 80/443 from anywhere, so lambda can't access this server anymore.

- the ec2 and lmabda is in same amazon account and same region.
- how i can give that lmabda function exception to access the ec2?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would configure the Lambda function to run inside the same VPC as the EC2 instance. Then configure the security group attached to the EC2 instance to only allow traffic on port 80/443 originating from the security group assigned to the Lambda function.

Comment: after two days i was do that before i got answer here.
but thank you for try to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to but them both in a [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/what-is-amazon-vpc.html) and control via [SecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html) that they can contact each other.

Comment: after two days i was do that before i got answer here.
but thank you for try to help :)